# What is the meaning of this line in a song?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I listened to "Congratulations", a song by the Youtuber Pewdiepie, and I'm having trouble figuring out what this line means:

There is no army in the world I'd rather give me watch time.

I don't understand what "giving watch time" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a soldier is given "watch time" they are assigned to guard duty.

Comment: Then what would the sentence mean?

Comment: There is no army in the world in which  I would prefer to do guard duty.